# Compiling part of a Python code (e.g. x modules out of n)

Tags: python, compilation

I would like to share my updates/evolutions of a Python Software but I would like to keep 'hidden' the main code.

For example I have

```
Configuration_File_Main_Code.xml
Main_Code_Start.py (this is the main... the executable)
Main_Code_Aux_1.py (associated auxiliary module for the Main_Code_Start.py)
...
Main_Code_Aux.n.py (the last associated auxiliary module for the Main_Code_Start.py)
```

and then

```
Configuration_File_My_Evolution.xml
My_Evolution_main.py (my implementation. There is a entry point in the Main_Code_Start.py)
My_Evolution_Aux.py (associated auxiliary module for the My_Evolution_main.py)
```

The idea is to have all the  modules belonging to the Main complied while keeping My_Evolution visibile for inspection or further modification.

The Configuration Files of the Main_Code_Start should be visible and indipendent.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Best!

The idea would be to have something like:

```
Configuration_File_Main_Code.xml
Main_Code_Start Compiled and executable
Configuration_File_My_Evolution.xml
My_Evolution_main.py 
My_Evolution_Aux.py
```

Comment: Well, the main goal of *compiling* a Python application is to build a self contained executable that can be installed on a system without any prior Python installation. Hiding the source is only a side effect and anyway the *executable* does contains the *.pyc* files which can be *decompiled*. That decompilation does produce hard to read source, but you must be aware that if somebody really wants to know the content of a *compiled Python application*, they will be able to after some work. IMHO, you should avoid to apply technical solutions for legal questions...

Comment: Dear Serge,
Thank you for your comment and for pointing this out. The main code is available to the people that will review my implementation, so the purpose of ‘hiding’ the main code is not for legal or proprietary reason, but just to give them a ‘demo’ focusing on my implementation. 
It is also a procedure that I would like to learn.
Best!